# Invalid syntax Core().Run() in Python

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am trying to run some code and execute with:

```
Core().Run()
```

However I get the error:

There is an error in your program
invalid syntax

and following after the

```
Core().Run()
```

is a long red bar in Idle. Any help with how I can run the program?

The full code:

```
import os
import sys
import mp3play
try:
    # for Python2
    from Tkinter import *

    class Core():

        def __init__(self):

            self.Music = os.listdir(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Music'))
            self.MusicPath = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'),'Music')
            print(self.Music)

            self.count = ''
            self.mp3 = ''
            self.VolumeSlider = ''
            self.count = 0

            self.createRoot()
            self.createButtons()

            self.LoadSong(False)



        def createRoot(self, w = 729, h = 170):

            self.root = Tkinter.aTk()
            self.root.option_add('*Font', 'courier 12')
            self.root.option_add('*Background', 'light blue')
            self.root.configure(bg='light blue')

            ws = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()
            hs = self.root.winfo_screenheight()
            x = (ws/2) - (w/2)    
            y = (hs/2) - (h/2)



        def createButtons(self):

            Tkinter.Button(self.root, height=2, width=10, text='◄◄', borderwidth=10,command=self.BackwardSong, fg = 'black', bg='light blue').grid(row=0,column=0)
            Tkinter.Button(self.root, height=2, width=10, text='►', borderwidth=10,command=self.PlayButton, fg = 'black', bg='light blue').grid(row=0,column=1)

            self.buttonPause = Tkinter.Button(self.root, height=2, width=10, text='║║', borderwidth=10,command=self.PauseButton, fg = 'black', bg='light blue')
            self.buttonPause.grid(row=0, column=2)

            Tkinter.Button(self.root, height=2, width=10, text='■', borderwidth=10,command=self.StopButton, fg = 'black', bg='light blue').grid(row=0,column=3)
            Tkinter.Button(self.root, height=2, width=10, text='►►', borderwidth=10,command=self.ForwardSong, fg = 'black', bg='light blue').grid(row=0,column=4)
            Tkinter.Button(self.root, height=2, width=10, text='Quit', borderwidth=10,command=self.Quit, fg = 'black', bg='light blue').grid(row=1,column=1)
            self.VolumeSlider = Tkinter.Scale(self.root, length = 140, label='  Volume ', orient = 'horizontal', fg = 'black', bg='light blue', command = self.VolAdj).grid(row=1, column=2)    




        def LoadSong(self, play=True):
            self.mp3 = self.mp3play.load(os.path.join(self.MusicPath, self.Music[self.count]))
            if play:
                self.mp3.play()  




        def PlayNextSongAuto(self):

            track = 0
            while track < self.mp3.seconds():
                self.root.after(3600)
                track += 1
            self.count = 0
            self.LoadSong()  




        def ForwardSong(self):
            Stop = len(self.Music) - 2
            print(Stop)
            if self.count > Stop:
                print('End of Play List')
                self.count = 0
                raw_input('')
                self.Quit()    
            self.StopButton()        
            self.count += 1
            self.LoadSong()  




        def BackwardSong(self):
            if self.count > -3:            
                print('End of Play List')
                self.Quit()        
            self.StopButton()
            self.count -= 1
            self.LoadSong()  


        def PlayButton(self):
            self.buttonPause.configure(text = '║║', command=self.PauseButton)
            self.mp3.play()


        def PauseButton(self):
            self.buttonPause.configure(text = 'Unpause', command=self.UnPauseButton)
            if self.mp3.isplaying():
                self.mp3.pause()


        def UnPauseButton(self):
            self.buttonPause.configure(text = '║║', command=self.PauseButton)
            if self.mp3.ispaused():
                self.mp3.unpause() 

        def StopButton(self):
            self.buttonPause.configure(text = '║║', command=self.PauseButton)
            self.mp3.stop()


        def Quit(self):
            self.StopButton()
            sys.exit('')


        def VolAdj(self, val):
            self.mp3.volume(val)


        def Run(self):
            self.root.mainloop()



    Core().Run()
```

Comment: The syntax you posted isnt obviously incorrect. Can you post the rest of your program? The issue is likely elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a large try block without an except clause; since the last line is `Core().Run()`, this is where the error occurs.

It think what you want to do is this:

```
import os
import sys
import mp3play
try:
    # for Python2
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *

# The rest of your code here
```